# Diagonalization of block circulant matrix with circulant blocks

Tags: matlab, matrix, fft

Let `A` be a block circulant matrix with circulant blocks (*i.e* a BCCB matrix):

```
A = [1 2 3 4
     2 1 4 3
     3 4 1 2
     4 3 2 1]
```

that is:

```
 A = [C1 C2
      C2 C1]
```

where each block (`C1`, `C2`) is a [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). I've read (see [here](http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/seminars/hs2010/ipip/slides.1.1.pdf)) that BCCB can be diagonalized by following the equation: `A =F*·D·F` where `F` is the 2-D discrete Fourier transform matrix, `F*` is the conjugate of `F`, and `D` is a diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues of `A`.

In MATLAB I use this code:

```
(conj(dftmtx(4))/16*(fft2(A))*dftmtx(4))
```

but the result is:

```
[1 4 3 2
 2 3 4 1
 3 2 1 4
 4 1 2 3]
```

Here the second and the fourth columns of `A` are switched. Where is the error?

Comment: Your implementation doesn't seem to match the definition. Where's `d` coming from, and why did you apply `fft2` to it? Also, my intuition says to me that `F*` is supposed to be the [complex conjugate transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) matrix, not just the complex conjugate.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not `d`, but `A`.

Comment: Can you address the rest of my comment?

Comment: For a circulant matrix `a=[4 1 0; 0 4 1; 1 0 4]` I use: `conj(dftmtx(3))/3*(diag(fft(a(:,1))))*(dftmtx(3))`, since the fft of the first column of a circulant matrix gives the eigenvalues of the circulant matrix.

Comment: That doesn't really answer anything. Anywya, can you link to the article where you've read about this diagonalization process?

Comment: Pag 9, [here](http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/seminars/hs2010/ipip/slides.1.1.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your source is a bit misleading. Diagonalizing a BCCB matrix with DFT is done as follows:

> `A = (FM⊗FN)*D(FM⊗FN)`

where F<sub>N</sub> is the N-point DFT matrix, M is the number of C<sub>j</sub> blocks and N is the size of each individual block (in your example M=2 and N=2). The "⊗" symbol denotes the [*tensor product*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).

Also note that `F* = conj(F)T` (F<sup>*</sup> is called the [*complex conjugate transpose*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) matrix). In MATLAB it translates to `F'` instead of `conj(F)`. Coincidentally, the [DFT matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) `F` is [*symmetric*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix), which means that `F* = conj(F)` is also true.

I'm not sure what you are trying to compute, but here's how the diagonalization of `A` is done in MATLAB:

```
M = 2; N = 2;
FF = kron(dftmtx(M), dftmtx(N)); %// Tensor product
D = FF' * A * FF / size(A, 1);   %// ' is the conjugate transpose operator
```

which yields:

```
D =
    10    0    0    0
     0   -2    0    0
     0    0   -4    0
     0    0    0    0
```

To diagonalize `A` using only 2-D FFT operations, you can do this instead:

```
c = reshape(A(:, 1), N, []);     %// First column of each block
X = fft2(c);
D = diag(X(:));
```

or in a one-liner:

```
D = diag(reshape(fft2(reshape(A(:, 1), N, [])), [], 1));
```

All of these produce the same diagonal matrix `D`.

Hope this clarifies things for you!

Comment: Nice. Your second solution is of course exactly what was described in the [PDF slides](http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/seminars/hs2010/ipip/slides.1.1.pdf).

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thank you. Another question: what about multilevel circular matrix? That is, if we have a BCCB matrix where each block is a BCCB matrix, is it possible to generalize the diagonalization, and if yes, how?

Comment: @no_name Unfortunately, I'm not aware of such generalization. Perhaps you can get more insights by posting a new question on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)...

Comment: Maybe I found an answer [here](http://insubriaspace.cilea.it/bitstream/10277/318/1/TesiPhD-Sesana.pdf). Take a look at page 102. What do you think?

Comment: I know this question has been solved and this post is from a long time ago, but since the above links are dead, I thought I would share a reference that I found super helpful in case it helps others too. 

A summary of almost everything related to circulant matrices called "Circulant Matrices and Their Application to Vibration Analysis available" here: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01378829/.

Comment: @PhysicsEnthusiast Thanks for your input. However, which of the above links gives you probelms? They all work for me.

Comment: @Eitan T your links work! I meant the two links in the comments posted by horchler and no_name. I should have worded it better.